# Перечислить все элементы класса

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброго времени суток. Есть HTML код:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="en">

        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="ru">

        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="en">

        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="ru">

        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Пытаюсь каждому элементу класса "en" дать последовательный id —
JavaScript:

```
for(var i=0;i<$('.en').get().length;i++){
    $('.en').attr('id', i).index(i);
}
```

В итоге все элементы получают один и тот же id. ЧЯДНТ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    var elems = $(".en");
    var elemsTotal = elems.length;
    for(var i=0; i<elemsTotal; ++i){$(elems[i]).attr('id', i)}

 })
```

Comment: Да, большое спасибо. Вообще, достаточно было добавить обращение к конкретному элементу через :eq(), т.е. так:  

    for(var i=0;i<$('.en').get().length;i++){
        $('.en:eq(' + i + ')').attr('id', i);
    }

Comment: В вашем случае да, в общем - нет.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div.en').each(function(idx){this.id=idx});
```